# How to write unit test for URI create in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, junit4, junit5

Below is the method I'm trying to write unit test using junit 5

```
@Value("${proxy.host}")
    private String endpoint;

public Request<Void> setAwsRequestGETParameter(String setStatusPath) {
        Request<Void> requestAws = new DefaultRequest<Void>("sts");
        requestAws.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);
        requestAws.setEndpoint(URI.create(endpoint));
        requestAws.setResourcePath(setStatusPath);
        return requestAws;
    }
```

Below is the unit test I'm trying to run

```
@InjectMocks
    private AWSAuthHandler testAWSAuthHandler;

@Test
    public void testSetAwsRequestGETParameter() throws Exception {
        URI mockedURI = Mockito.mock(URI.class);
        assertNotNull(testAWSAuthHandler.setAwsRequestGETParameter("/status/7deaed5e-3080-45ec-89ba-403977d60c0c"));
    }
```

Below is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3106)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:600)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:881)
```

Can someone please help me with the missing part? Thank you

Comment: That is why property injection is not a good idea, use constructor injection instead, that way you can construct a properly initialized object of `AWSAuthHandler` with a dummy `endpoint`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you please share an example or reference to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

For setting properties of class that you can't mock you can use Spring Reflection Utils, like that:

```
ReflectionUtils.setField(field, target, value);
```

where the field is the name of the field which you want to set ("endpoint" for your case),

target is the mocked class (testAWSAuthHandler for your case)

value is the wanted value

Answer (score 0):

As Sweta Sharma said, you need to initialise `AWSAuthHandler` with some value for `endpoint` field. That's why it is better to use constructor injection rather than field one.

Assuming your `AWSAuthHandler` class look like this (as you didn't provide the code for the whole class):

```java
public class AWSAuthHandler {

    @Value("${proxy.host}")
    private String endpoint;

    public Request<Void> setAwsRequestGETParameter(String setStatusPath) {
        Request<Void> requestAws = new DefaultRequest<Void>("sts");
        requestAws.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);
        requestAws.setEndpoint(URI.create(endpoint));
        requestAws.setResourcePath(setStatusPath);
        return requestAws;
    }
```

You can refactor it in the following way:

```java
public class AWSAuthHandler {

    private String endpoint;

    public AWSAuthHandler(@Value("${proxy.host}") String endpoint) {
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public Request<Void> setAwsRequestGETParameter(String setStatusPath) {
        Request<Void> requestAws = new DefaultRequest<Void>("sts");
        requestAws.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);
        requestAws.setEndpoint(URI.create(endpoint));
        requestAws.setResourcePath(setStatusPath);
        return requestAws;
    }
```

Then you can create tests for this class:

```java
private AWSAuthHandler testAWSAuthHandler;

@BeforeEach
void setUpTests() {
    this.testAWSAuthHandler = new AWSAuthHandler("some-endpoint-here");
}

@Test
public void testSetAwsRequestGETParameter() throws Exception {
   assertNotNull(testAWSAuthHandler.setAwsRequestGETParameter("/status/7deaed5e-3080-45ec-89ba-403977d60c0c"));
}
```

You can read more about Spring `@Value` annotation here, for example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation